# Shopify custom setting page for app

Tags: api, sdk, shopify, liquid

I tried searching up and down, but haven't found any thing that would even give a hint. My question is, If it is possible to create a custom setting page for a custom (public/private) app with Shopify?

What I want to achieve, is something like a custom setting page for my custom app.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: have you got any solution? I am also looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

Like all other apps from shopify app directory, You can also create settings page for your custom app (private/public).

You just need to develop the settings page for your app and allow its access to verified users.

Comment: Thanks. Could you maybe point me to the direct from where I can start with this?

Comment: Have you developed the app yet ? What programming language you used or planning to use ? Do you have shopify partner account ?

Comment: I have partner account, but i haven't really started to developed yet. I was doing R&D atm. But it will be with PHP.

Comment: @Zubair1 have you got any solution for this so far. I am also looking for this.

Comment: @MashR. can you tell me what should I do to create a custom page for my custom shopify app. I am just learning shopify app creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your app settings on Shopify store, then you have to develop a public app. You can't achieve this with the private app.

Except showing app setting on Shopify admin you can do all the things that you want in Shopify.

Please, check [the Shopify tutorial to develop the public app](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/building-public-app)